# Pipe STDIN to a script that is itself being piped to the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, bash, svn, pipe, pre-commit-hook

I need to implement an SVN pre-commit hook which executes a script that itself is stored in SVN.

I can use the `svn cat` command to pipe that script to the Python interpreter, as follows:

```
svn cat file://$REPO/trunk/my_script.py | python - --argument1 --argument2
```

However, `my_script.py` itself requires data to be piped on STDIN.

That data is not stored in a file; it is stored on the network. I would prefer not to have to download the data to a temporary file, as normally I could pipe it to a Python program:

```
curl http://example.com/huge_file.txt | python my_script.py
```

I'm not sure how to combine both of these pipes.

Comment: Write a wrapper script that uses pysvn to read in the file, then compile and exec it, so your stdin is free?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out how to do this without creating any temporary files, but not strictly with "pipes".

`curl http://example.com/huge_file.txt | python <(svn cat file://$REPO/trunk/my_script.py) --argument1 --argument2`

I used the "anonymous file descriptor" construct in Bash, which can be used in place of any file path.

E.g.
`python my_script.py`
would be equivalent to
`python <(cat my_script.py)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You feed the script as standard input to the python interpreter. This means that the python interpreter is already attached to an input stream. I don't think the script contents can create a second standard input to read from.